# On my ponytail palm next to the trunk newer leaves are brown. Ive benn peeling them off but its still growing brown leaves. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: diagnosis

The leaves in question is growing from top of trunk.  They are coming out brown.  I've peeled them off, but still producing brown leaves

Comment: Please post a photo